# I want to add a glyphicon which is not included in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, glyphicons

I want to add some of the glyphicons to my website which are not included in the Bootstrap 3 files like `.eot`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff`. So, how to add them?

[image]

With that sign in I want to add a glyphicon which shows we are adding users
eg:http://glyphicons.com in here the first row, 7 column which is user_add glyphicon UTF+007

Comment: if you want to use the glphyicons that arent included with twitter bootstrap, you will need to purchase a pro version of the glyphicons library. This will give you access to new .eot, .svg, .woff and .tff files, as well as updated css and html files for class names

Comment: alternatively you can have a look at something like http://fontastic.me/ which allows you to create, or use some of their prebuilt icon fonts, to fill anything that doesnt come free with twitter bootstrap

Comment: You might also consider using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) instead, which is free.

Comment: @cvrebert But can you please suggest any easier way?